# Bash while loop error

Tags: bash, while-loop

This is a simple school project.  The console keeps stating [5:command not found

```
#!/bin/bash

num=28
echo "Guess a number a number between 1 and 100"
read guess

while [$guess -ne $num]
do

 if [$guess -lt $num]
 then
     echo "number is higher"
 elif [$guess -gt $num]
 then
     echo "number is lower"
  else
     echo "Correct! The number is $number"
  fi

done
```

Comment: You need to turn on command tracing to see what you are doing.  You haven't quoted the script, so I have to guess about command separation, but I do not think there is command separation before the "read" command (i.e. a semicolon or a new line).  Anyway, add a "set -x" line.

Answer (score 2):

```
while [$guess -ne $num]
```

is interpreted by first expanding the parameters:

```
while [5 -ne 28]
```

which then causes the command `[5` to be executed, passing it arguments `-ne` and `28]`

You wanted to execute the command `[`, so you needed to write:

```
while [ $guess -ne $num ]
```

(Note the spaces around both `[` and `]`. Without the space, the characters become part of another word.)

Ditto with the statements following `if` and `elif`.

Comment: thank you.  I didn't realize it needed spacing to understand the condition

Comment: @keebler: the important takeaway is that `[` is a _command_. As a character, it is not special; `[23` would be a different command, which you could implement as an executable file with that name. If you look around, probably in `/usr/bin`, you'll find a file named `[`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=28
echo "Guess a number a number between 1 and 100" 
read guess

while [ $guess -ne $num ]; do
  if [ $guess -lt $num ]
  then
    echo "number is higher" 
    read guess
  elif [ $guess -gt $num ]
  then
    echo "number is lower" 
    read guess
  fi
done
echo "Correct! The number is $number"
```